# Why doesn't DBI (DBD::Pg) return the correct column type for text for my ad-hoc query?

Tags: perl, dbi

What's with this?

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q~

    select 'hello'::text as my_text_column

~);
$sth->execute;

print $$sth{TYPE}[0]; # prints -1, expected 12
```

I can `select 5` and it returns the correct type (`4`, for integer) or cast it like `select 5::numeric(4, 2)` and get back `3`.  Why doesn't it like text columns?

Comment: The reason I expect `12` is from running `$dbh->type_info_all`.  There's no type corresponding to `-1` in there, but `text` has a `DATA_TYPE` of `12`.

Comment: `$sth->{TYPE[0]` would be more readable.

Comment: I actually prefer the `$$` notation.  I find it easier both to type and to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question, but as a workaround, you could use the postgres-specific `$sth->{pg_type}` rather than `$sth->{TYPE}`.

In your example, `$sth->{pg_type}->[0]` would return 'text'.